# SVD in concepts space, example

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, svd

I've recently come across [this video](https://youtu.be/P5mlg91as1c?si=3k1-E_WNWeLkrPl5&t=466) where SVD is explained using so called *concepts*, on the example of users and film ratings. The matrix $U$, containing left singular vectors, is interpreted as "user-to-concept" similarity matrix, whereas matrix $V^T$ is interpreted as "movie-to-concept" similarity matrix.

Although this example seems somewhat intuitive and very illustrative, I have hard time understanding why we can think of SVD in such way. In terms of linear transformation SVD is simply a roration, followed by stretching and another rotation, but why are we so sure that the two first left singular vectors happen to be responsible for (in this case) sc-fi and romance concept, respectively?

Comment: I don't have time to write out a detailed answer, but for interpreting the SVD in this context you should think of the input to the SVD as not being a linear transformation but a bilinear pairing, in this case a pairing between "user space" and "film space." Then the idea is that the left and right singular vectors "diagonalize" this pairing.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. However, I do not necessarily see a connection here. Would it be possible for you to provide a more detailed answer? I'd really appreciate.

Comment: To clarify the bilinear form a bit: suppose that $A$ is $m \times n$. A unit vector $u \in \Bbb R^m$ is a unit-vector in "user space" (corresponding to a sort of weighted sampling of users), and a vector $v \in \Bbb R^n$ is similarly a unit-vector in "movie space". The bilinear form $\langle u,v \rangle = u^TAv$ tells us how much the group of users likes the group of movies. In the particular case that $u$ and $v$ correspond to a single user and single movie, this just amounts to reading an entry from the matrix.

Comment: The goal of SVD, then, is to find the pairs of groups whose interaction allows us to most accurately predict how much a new group of users would like a new group of movies with a simplified ("low-dimensional") model.